# how to sum up a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

Given a list of strings as such,

```
xs = ['1\n','2\n','3\n','4\n','5\n']
```

sum up the integers to return the sum as a string and append the sum to the list so that the returned list

```
xs = ['1\n','2\n','3\n','4\n','5\n','Sum:15\n']
```

I understand the process of going through the list and iterating this, I just don't understand how to get rid of the `\n` character so that I can only use the integer to find the sum?

Comment: Did Regular expression not work?

Comment: What is up with this weird list and the way you are storing the sum at the end and all the newlines?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Educated guess: reading lines from a file and wanting to append the sum to the end, maybe. Obviously not the best way to do it if that's the case, but I give credit to the OP for trying to come up with *something* on their own.

Comment: @jpmc26 Maybe that's why OP did it but doing that hardly requires this funky construction. Could just sum normally and open the file with the `'a'` option.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist See my edited comment. ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question a bit more directly (leaving out the iteration since you said that's not the problem):

Believe it or not, `int` actually ignores the trailing newline when you use it to parse:

```
>>> int('1\n')
1
```

Once you have an `int`, you can do arithmetic as normal.

This is a documented feature in Python 2 and 3:

> Optionally, the literal can be preceded by + or - (with no space in between) and **surrounded by whitespace**.

-[Python `int` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) (emphasis mine)

If you're interested in more streamlined ways of doing the iteration, you can see [Joran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36510641/1394393) and the comments on it, but if this is some kind of assignment, I wouldn't use them if I were you. It benefits you more to work through the problems yourself. You of course want to use the more advanced features for professional work.

Answer (score 2):

```
def my_fun(x):
    return x+["Sum: %s\n"%sum(map(int,x)),]
```

Comment: I had no idea Python would ignore whitespace when parsing an `int`. The sum can also be written using a comprehension or generator, if preferred: `sum(int(i) for i in xs)`.

Comment: At first I was like, "Eww, why did you do that", then I saw who it was, looked up, and wow. What a required expected output.

Answer (score 1):

This uses a generator:

```
>>> xs + ['Sum:{0}\n'.format(str(sum(int(s) for s in xs)))]
['1\n', '2\n', '3\n', '4\n', '5\n', 'Sum:15\n']
```